# Supporting hyperplance theorem proof.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, optimization, proof-explanation, convex-optimization, compactness

I've read the proof of supporting hyperplane theorem [here](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/%7Eangelia/L7_separationthms.pdf) (page 5 in pdf)  I have some questions regarding the proof, that are not clear for me now.

Also I include the proof image here: [image]

1. Why $\{x_k\} \nsubseteq C : x_k \rightarrow x.$ exists?
2. Why the sequence $a_k = \frac{x_k -z^*_k}{||x_k - z^*_k||} \text{ for } k \ge 1.$ is bounded?
3. How from projection theorem result: $a^T_kz^*_k=a^T_k(z^*_k-x_k) + a^T_kx_k < a^T_kx_k \text{  } \forall k, $ we can say that $a^T_kz < a^T_kx_k \text{  } \forall z \in C.$?

Comment: You copy and paste a picture, and ask three questions, with no context whatsoever from you? One question per post, please add context to improve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because $C$ is closed and either $x_0 \in \text{Bd}(C)$ (so all neighbourhoods of $x_0$ intersect $\Bbb R^n\setminus C$) or $x_0 \notin C$. In either case $x_0 \in \overline{\Bbb R^n\setminus C}$ and closure is sequential closure in metric spaces.
2. $\|a_k\| = 1$ for all $k$, so that's clear.
3. Combine the two equations: $a^T_kz^\ast \le a^Tz^\ast_k < a_k^Tx_k$ so $a^T_kz^\ast < a_k^Tx_k$ follows. ($a \le b < c$ implies $a < c$ in any linear order).